# Android ActivityManager ActivityRecord Crash

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, android-activityrecord

My app is crashing. No real stack trace comes up, the exception is not showing up in the logs nor in fabric/crashlytics. After setting no filters in the logcat and manually looking for some indication of what could be going on I found these logs:

```
E/ActivityManager: Found activity ActivityRecord{2e94fa u0 com.myapp/com.myapp.activities.MainActivity t4321 f} in proc activity list using null instead of expected ProcessRecord{cb93d5a 13704:com.myapp/u0a447}
11-30 10:15:07.953 4802-14994/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 13704:com.myapp/u0a447 (adj 0): crash
11-30 10:15:07.953 4802-14994/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord — 13704
```

**EDIT**: This happens when a new activity is started from within the main activity => the new activity shows up & includes a Mapview, could the mapView be the underlying problem?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DriveMapActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Any information on this would be great!

Comment: Does this happen right away, or after a specific action? Please post the code of your `MainActivity` and your manifest.